# Paytm Integration using Angular 6

Tags: angular, paytm

I am using the same html form used to integrate paytm in php, but I am not getting redirected to paytm server's page.Kindly help.

Comment: You can replace the url itself in client side getting all query details from backend. Only the problem I am facing is, once it is redirected to the angular page, I want to get the request data in the page to show if it is success or failed.

Answer (score 1):

since Paytm api not support AJAX/REST, we have to send  a post request to their gate way url.To do so, create that form in this way.

```
  <form #form ngNoForm method="post" action="https://securegwstage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction">
```

so ngNoForm will prevent the dfault nature of angular forms.